Launch Swagger Docs Automatically using env file based boolean flag
I was able to successfully get the Swagger URL to launch when the node js app runs with the following code.

open(swaggerURL, { app: { name: 'chrome' } });


This is great. Then, I realized, it can get annoying when I don't want this to do this all the time. So, I created a env variable like this.
LAUNCH_BROWSER_AUTOMATICALLY=true

and added the following flag check. However, the swagger url is not being launched automatically when the flag is set to true.

      console.log(process.env.LAUNCH_BROWSER_AUTOMATICALLY);
      

      if(process.env.LAUNCH_BROWSER_AUTOMATICALLY == true)
      {
        open(swaggerURL, { app: { name: 'chrome' } });
      }

I can see in the terminal that the env value is being read.
Connected to MongoDB. Nodemon Working
Server is running on http://localhost:3000
Swagger docs available at http://localhost:3000/api-docs
true

So, how would be I make this work? How can I control the 'open' URL setting from the env file (if this is not the right way to do it)

Found the solution for your problem.
The problem with the retrieving boolean values from .env is that it  returns the value as string. So you can do a simple string operation as follows:
  if (process.env.LAUNCH_BROWSER_AUTOMATICALLY === "true") {
        open(swaggerURL, { app: { name: "chrome" } });
      }

Or you can use JSON.parse for parsing the value then it should work:
  if (JSON.parse(process.env.LAUNCH_BROWSER_AUTOMATICALLY) === true) {
        open(swaggerURL, { app: { name: "chrome" } });
      }


I tried that, made no difference.

Could you share the source code or anything so I can reproduce this.

the code is already pubilc. you can see it here, https://github.com/Jay-study-nildana/FrontEndForStudents/tree/main/NodeJSForStudents/mongodbhwnov2024a

Updated the solution, check if this works out.

will check and update my friend. thank you.
